# Может ли быть другая проверка исключений кроме try-catch?

Tags: java, исключения, try-catch

1.Может ли быть другая проверка исключений кроме try catch?

2.Если в блоке try запустить исключение `... throw ex; ...`, а в заголовке  `catch(Exeption ex)`, то когда мы дойдем до исключения в `try` запустится ли блок `catch` или программа вылетит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Нет. Если функция бросила исключение, то мы либо его ловим с помощью catch на каком нибудь уровне, либо наша программа вылетает.
Но когда мы его поймали можно его проверять уже другими средствами. Например if (exс instanceof IOException) ... Но как правило на практике такое редко когда нужно.

2) Да, без разницы выбросит это исключение функция или мы сами. Можно сделать и так:

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Этот код будет выполнятся всегда.
}
```

Но так делать крайне не рекомендуется, потому что это противоречит идеалогии исключений. Если мы можем обработать ошибку на текущем уровне (то бишь в рамках текущей функции) мы исключение не выбрасываем, а прямо тут обрабатываем. Как следствие лучше использовать if вместо try - catch, потому что большое количество обработок загружает программу, да и исключения обрабатываются крайнееееее медленно.

Кстати второй пункт вы вполне могли и сами проверить, в чем была проблема написать такой код и посмотреть - вылетит или нет?

Comment: А мы можем делать что-нибудь с буквой е(не знаю как называется) в блоке?

Comment: Да, буковка "e" это просто переменная, в которую записывается объект исключения. Нажмите ctrl + пробел и смотрите список методов. Как правило там можно получить информацию об исключении (стек вызовов или сообщение), либо самому подредактировать (добавить вложенное исключение - причину). Более того, это исключение можно снова выбросить через throw e; В общем не считая возможности "выбрасываться" в остальном это обычный java-объект.

Answer (score 1):

1) Ручная *if*-ами или *switch*-ом 
2) **Exception** - суперкласс для исключений, соответственно, любое исключение (даже написанное Вами, если вы при создании исключения наследовались от **Exception**) будет ловиться блоком *catch*

Comment: `Exception ` наследуется от `Throwable`, так что не любое исключение. 
Любое исключение поймает только  `Throwable`

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, я примерно ждал такого комментария, на что могу ответить, что throwable имеет 2 потомка - error (*непроверяемые (unchecked)* ошибки) и exception (исключения), соответственно error сигнализирует о ненормальной работе программы и их не рекомендуют обрабатывать, тогда как исключения (exception) должны обрабатываться.

Comment: Заметьте, что у Throwable есть поле/свойство cause тоже типа Throwable, что как бы подразумевает, что всё Throwable могут быть обработаны. Иначе зачем Throwable в качестве cause?

Comment: @sergey, а никто и не спорит о возможности обработки throwable) "дилема" скорее в том, целесообразно ли обрабатывать такое исключение или решить проблему возникновения такого исключения в коде. Но, это касается ошибок типа error.